# Lower Semicontinuity of the Fundamental Group

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Gromov-Hausdorff convergence of compact metric spaces certainly do not preserve topology. However, at the level of fundamental group, for length spaces the following result is well known (I think):

*Let* $ \{  X_n \} _{n \in \mathbb{N} }$   *be a sequence of compact length spaces converging to a compact length space* $X$. *Assume there is* $ \varepsilon > 0 $ *such that every ball of radius* $ \varepsilon$ *in* $X$ *is simply connected. Then for large enough* $n$, *there are surjective morphisms (for any choice of basepoints)*
$$\pi_1 (X_n) \to \pi_1(X)$$

When $X$ is a torus, the morphisms can be obtained from continuous maps $X_n \to X$.

Is there a reference for this result (or a result that implies this one)?